# jquery ui multiple sliders with default value and combined max

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make a page where people can give points to several interests.

There is a maximum of 50 points, and I want to spread this with several sliders. Because it is saved in the DB, there will be a default value per interest.

Already found a lot online, and after hours of ^@^## it still does not work. If I give one slider a (default) value, the rest doesn't work anymore. I tried a lot of things, but now I really don;t know anymore.

What do I do wrong? Or will this never work with my code? I am still learning :(

html

```
        <p>total available points  50 </p>
    <div id="sliders">
      <div>
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <input type="text" class="value" value="0" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <input type="text" class="value" value="0" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <input type="text" class="value" value="7" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <input type="text" class="value" value="0" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <input type="text" class="value" value="0" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <input type="text" class="value" value="0" />
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

javascript

```
          $(window).load(function(){

      var sliders = $("#sliders .slider");
      var availableTotal = 50;

      sliders.each(function() {

          $(this).empty().slider({

             value: 0,
              min: 0,
              max: 50,
              range: "max",
              step: 1,
              animate: 100,     
               create: function () {
                  $(this).slider( "option", "value", $(this).next().val() );
              },         
              slide: function(event, ui) {

                  // Get current total
                  var total = 0;   

                  sliders.not(this).each(function() {
                      total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
                  });    

                  var max = availableTotal - total;            

                  if (max - ui.value >= 0) {
                      // Need to do this because apparently jQ UI
                      // does not update value until this event completes
                      total += ui.value;
                     // console.log(max-ui.value);
                      $(this).siblings().val(ui.value);

                  } else {
                      return false;
                  }


                  //get total sum of all points
                  var sum = 0;
                  $(".value").each(function(){
                      sum += +$(this).val();
                  });
                  $(".total").text(sum);

              }
          });
      });
      });
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ks2p4kgk/)

Comment: I updated the code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/d5w5n0co/ ) but I jsut can't get the standard value working

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if Id add a function that in the begining all the sliders are set? The value of the input boxes will be set by php.